# How to use Google Drive API in Android Cordova Phonegap application?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-drive-android-api

I have been searching for the right resources for syncing files with Google Drive by Drive API from the Cordova application. As I can see so many links, from that many are deprecated and some are about to shut down by Google.

And I try to use google packages like this `com.google.andriod.gms.*` it ends up with `not resolved` on Eclipse IDE. But I have installed all the Google Play Services and Google APIs from Andriod SDK manager. Not sure what is wrong there

Can anyone please help me with this? I am new to this development. It would be great if someone who guide me in the right way to achieve this Google Drive sync from Cordova application.

Comment: Refer to their Firebase library and examples, if not there, then they are not supporting this anymore due to privacy concerns.

Comment: @andreszs It would be better if you can suggest some links to refer to this? I am new to this. Could you please? Thanks

Comment: @andreszs is there any useful resource for this? Please help